# mongoose-gridstore display Image in the Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I use 'mongoose-Gridstore' to save files in my Mongo database. My problem is to display these files in the browser. The 'Content-Type' is set and the data is also loaded but not displayed.

My Route

```
router.route('/:image_id').get(function (req, res) {

Image.findById(req.params.image_id, function (err, image) {
    image.loadAttachments()
        .then(function (doc) {
            doc.attachments.forEach(function (attachment) {
                console.log(attachment.filename);
                console.log(attachment.mimetype);
                console.log(attachment);
                res.header("Content-Type", attachment.mimetype);
                res.send(attachment);

            });
                      })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('error loading all attachments');
            throw err;
        });
});
```

Attachment looks like this:

```
    { _gsId: 56713c78ba1df3800e816ce5,
  filename: 'IMG_5857.JPG',
  buffer: <Buffer 2f 39 6a 2f 34 56 62 59 52 58 68 70 5a 67 41 41 53 55 6b 71 41 41 67 41 41 41 41 4d 41 41 38 42 41 67 41 47 41 41 41 41 6e 67 41 41 41 42 41 42 41 67 ... >,
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this. add this response in img tag you will get the image

```
router.route('/:image_id').get(function (req, res) {
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
mongoose.connection.once('open', function () {
 var gfs = new Grid(mongoose.connection.db, mongoose.mongo);
 });   

Image.findById(req.params.image_id, function (err, image) {
image.loadAttachments()
    .then(function (doc) {
        doc.attachments.forEach(function (attachment) {

var rstream = gfs.createReadStream(attachment.filename);

    var bufs = [];
    rstream.on('data', function (chunk) {
        bufs.push(chunk);

    }).on('error', function () {
        res.send();
    })
            .on('end', function () { // done

                var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
                var imageFile = (fbuf.toString('base64'));
                var ret = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageFile;
                res.send(ret);
            });



        });
                  })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error loading all attachments');
        throw err;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but it´s not working. Can you tell me why my code does not work?

Comment: Browser does not recieve data and it is loading endlessly. After 4 minutes Browser stop loading.

Comment: In the `Chrome Developer Tools` under `Network` is the correct loaded size , but under `Resources -> Frames -> Images` is the image with the correct `mime type`, but the `Dimensions` and `File size` are 0. Why?

Comment: If i delete the line `res.setHeader("Content-Type", attachment.mimetype);`i get a base 64 code. I copied the code and decode it on this page http://base64online.org/decode/. It shows me my uploaded image. I do not understand what is my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If i delete the line res.setHeader("Content-Type", attachment.mimetype);i get a base 64 code. I copied the code and decode it on this page base64online.org/decode. It shows me my uploaded image. I do not understand where my mistake should be.